# React Redux form - When I trigger an update action and call a dispatch on another function, my list doesn't get updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a submit function in a redux form that is supposed to update a list of customers once a user either hits "Create customer" or "Update customer".

When the user clicks "Create customer", it creates the customer and fires a `this.props.dispatch(fetchCustomers());` to grab the updated list. However, when I click "Update Customer", it doesn't fetch the updated data. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my function in my component:

```
submit(formProps) {

      const customer = {
        name: formProps.get('name'),
        director: formProps.get('director'),
        manager: formProps.get('manager'),
        supervisor: formProps.get('supervisor'),
        contact: {
          name: formProps.get('contact').get('name'),
          phone_number: formProps.get('contact').get('phone_number'),
          email: formProps.get('contact').get('email'),
        },
      };

      // Are we editing?
      if(this.state.isEditingCustomer) {
        customer['_id'] = this.state.customer._id;
        this.props.dispatch(updateCustomer(customer));
      } else {
        // Dispatch action to convert the request to a work order
        this.props.dispatch(createCustomer(customer));
      }

      // Get the users
      this.props.dispatch(fetchCustomers());

      // Close the modal
      this.handleClose();
    }
```

Here is the action creator:

```
export function updateCustomer(customer) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_CUSTOMER,
    payload: customer,
    url: `/customer/${customer._id}`,
    success: UPDATE_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS,
  };
}
```

I am using sagas, so here is my `updateCustomerFlow` Saga:

```
export function* updateCustomerFlow() {
  while (true) {
    const request = yield take(UPDATE_CUSTOMER);
    const promise = yield call(putData1, true, request.url, request.payload);
    if (promise.status === 200) {
      yield put({ type: request.success, payload: promise.data.payload });
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `fetchCustomers` action creator:

```
export function fetchCustomers() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_CUSTOMERS,
    payload: null,
    url: '/customers/',
    success: FETCH_CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS,
  };
}
```

And my fetchCustomers saga:

```
export function* fetchCustomersFlow() {
  while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
    const request = yield take(FETCH_CUSTOMERS);
    const promise = yield call(getData1, true, request.url, request.payload);
    if (promise.status === 200) {
      yield put({ type: request.success, payload: promise.data.customers });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry where is the `fetchCustomers()` action creator? and also does `updateCustomer()` and `createCustomer()` already work?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I just added the action creator for `fetchCustomers()` as well. updateCustomer() and createCustomer() both do work, but for whatever reason when I run `updateCustomer()`, the `fetchCustomers()` doesn't seem to grab the latest results from the db. Perhaps there's a race condition?

Comment: As far as I can see, your updateCustomers will not have resolved before you then call fetchCustomers.

Comment: Ahh I see. I've read that you need to use something like redux-think to handle those types of race conditions. I inherited this project and I believe that since we're using sagas with the reducers, that has something to do with not necessarily needing redux-thunk? Is that right?